# Connecting to Websphere MQ via LDAP java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd in java.library.pat

Tags: binding, jndi, ibm-mq

I am attempting to connect to Websphere MQ 6 on Linux 64 bit running in a Sun 1.7 JDK.

I am trying to connect to the MQServer via JNDI looking up objects in LDAP as my application server is separate from the MQ Server and therefore I can't use the file system JNDI.

This all works fine on my development box but there I have 1) Windows and 2) have installed the MQ Server.

I can connect to the LDAP via Websphere MQ Explorer and create the binding objects in the LDAP.

The java application can access the JNDI objects and attempts to create a connection but I get an error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd in java.library.path

I have installed the 7.5 client from [here](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032744)

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to the defaults after running the command

```
. /opt/mqm/bin/setmqenv -s -l
```

The actual path is

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/java/default/jre/lib/i386:/opt/mqm/lib64/compat:/opt/mqm/lib/compat
```

I have also explicitly set -Djava.library.path=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH on the JVM.

But when I look at the path /opt/mqm/lib64/compat:/opt/mqm/lib/compat I can't see mqjbnd or anything like it.

A number of posts and tech discussions say that there is no mqjbnd in the client install only the server install. I'm getting confused as I only want to lookup the QueueManager and use the queue items via JNDI - should I just have to install the client rather than the server?

Is the LDAP method the right one for me to use? I attempted to use the com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory but could never get the security right for that.

Sorry but this is doing my head it - I can't help comparing this to the ease of connecting to ActiveMQ - I must be doing something wrong here.

Exception is

```
[2013-03-13 14:32:41,389] ERROR - ServiceTaskManager Error acquiring a JMS connection to : cn=ConnectionFactoryLdap using JNDI properties : {java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, java.naming.provider.url=ldap://LDAPSERVER:10389/dc=example,dc=com, transport.jms.ConnectionFactory=ibmMQQueueConnectionFactory, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue, serviceType=proxy}
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem.
See the linked exception for further information.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor30.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:233)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6863)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6254)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6189)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6218)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:555)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.createConnection(ServiceTaskManager.java:824)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.getConnection(ServiceTaskManager.java:706)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.receiveMessage(ServiceTaskManager.java:496)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(ServiceTaskManager.java:420)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd' was not found. For a client installation this is expected. [3=mqjbnd]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:304)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise_inner(LocalMQ.java:268)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise(LocalMQ.java:231)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.<init>(LocalMQ.java:1194)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalServer.<init>(LocalServer.java:206)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor29.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:732)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:666)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6855)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1138)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:279)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: This link talks about a similar issue with MQ v7. May be helpful to you. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413508

Comment: Thanks for that but I don't actually have the file /opt/mqm/java/lib/libmqjbnd.so mentioned - so maybe I need the server install or something on my application server?

Comment: This part of the exception puzzles me _For a client installation this is expected_

Comment: "application server is separate from the MQ Server and therefore I can't use the file system JNDI"  Your application server doesn't have a filesystem?  Typically, people use the JMSAdmin tool provided by IBM to edit the managed objects either on the MQ server and send the .bindings file to the app folks, or else they use it on the client node and manage it themselves.

Comment: Also, hover over the [tag:websphere-mq] tag, then select "info" and there you will find a veritable conrucopia of info to get started, including links to the MQ client downloads, the manuals, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the LDAP ConnnectionFactory transport was set to Bindings Mode.

I changed this to client mode as discussed [here][1]

Now I have an issue with authentication but is much better than having an issue with misconfigured or missing native libraries :) - make sure the Connection List points to the right servername(port).

Now I need to sort out authentication...

Comment: If you are using MQ v7.1 or higher, it comes secure by default.  Search the [tag:websphere-mq] tag for CHLAUTH and I have several answers explaining what to do. As a shortcut you can `ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)` to temporarily get past those auths errors but don't do that in Production! In fact, get up to speed in non-prod ASAP so you can turn `CHLAUTH` back on. If you are using MQ Explorer, download and install [MS0P](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0P) to help with the 2035 errors.  Please accept your own answer and post the 2035 errors as a separate question if you need to. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Open Tomcat Server -> Open lauch Configuration -> under Argument tab ->-Djava.library.path="C:\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib64"

it will resolved you exception , its is basically asking for runtime Library

Comment: -Djava.library.path="C:\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib64"   makre sure underScore should be available before D

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Path variable on system properties. Try to run code by specifying MQInstallation Dir :\Lib64 path before MQInstallation Dir :\Lib on path variable